# application: not a procedure mismatch error

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, non-procedure-application

I'm trying to implement a sort of read-write to cell function.

```
(define (read-write-get cell) (cell (list)))
(define (read-write-set cell x) (cell (list x)))

(define (read-write-cell x)
   (let ((cell '()))
       (read-write-set cell x)))

(define w1 (read-write-cell 10))
(check-equal? 10 (read-write-get w1))
```

I keep getting the error

> application: not a procedure;
>    expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
>     given: '()
>     arguments...:
>     errortrace...:

Comment: It's very difficult to guess what "a sort of read-write to cell function" would be, but I suspect that you would be helped by SICP's [chapter on assignment and local state](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-20.html#%_sec_3.1.1).

Answer (score 3):

In Scheme `(x y)` means apply the function `x` to the argument `y`. So

```
(define (read-write-set cell x) (cell (list x)))
```

defines a function `read-write-set` that, when called with the first parameter which is a function, applies that function, `cell`, to the result of evaluating `(list x)` (which build a list with the unique element the second parameter).

Then, in:

```
(define (read-write-cell x)
   (let ((cell '()))
       (read-write-set cell x)))
```

You call `read-write-set` with the first argument which is **not** a function, but an empty list (since `cell` is assigned to `'()` in the let).

So, “not a procedure; expected a procedure” refers to the value of the first argument to `read-write-set`, which is not a procedure but a list. It is not clear to me the intended behaviour of `read-write-get` and `read-write-set`, so I cannot suggest how to correct them.

Comment: I wrote some tests to describe what I'm attempting to implement                           
     (define a1 (read-write-cell 25))
     (check-equal? 25 (read-write-get a1))
     (define a2 (read-write-set a1 30))
     (check-equal? 30 (read-write-get a2))

Comment: @JohnSmith, you should decide how to implement the cell. As a closure (i.e. a function with an environment)? As a modifiable data structure? Or what else? The functions that you want to test are the *interface* to the cell abstraction, but the cell itself must be implemented in some specific, concrete, way.

Comment: I would like to implement it using closure. Do you know how I may be able to do that?

Comment: @JohnSmith, you can find a detailed discussion in the link provided in the comment of molbdnilo.